# Animate resizing UIView header of UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uistoryboard

Basically, I want to replicate the behavior in the login screen in Facebook for iPhone: when an input field is touched, the logo/header view decreases in height to make room for the keyboard.

Here I have a `UITableView` (with static content):

[image: My Login Scene]

The "Control" is really a `UIView` I have that contains the logo in a `UIImageView`, and the "Table View Section" contains the UITextFields for username/password.

My question is, how can I animate having the UIView ("Control") decreasing height, while having the `UITableViewCells` in "Table View Section" naturally slide up? I have tried the following:

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{
    CGRect theFrame = _headerView.frame;
    theFrame.size.height -= 50.f;
    _headerView.frame = theFrame;
}];
```

Where `_headerView` is the `UIView` for the header. It is resized, but the `UITableView` does not react as if a UITableViewCell was resized (i.e. the login UITableViewCells don't shift up). How can I fix this?

I have seen examples of how to resize a `UITableViewCell`, but I can't put the header/logo in a `UITableViewCell` as the table view section is grouped and shouldn't look like the login section.

### Edit

Great answer! Here's how I ended up animating it, with a `view_is_up` instance variable:

```
-(void)moveTableView:(BOOL)up{
    float move_distance = 55.f;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.3f];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
    UIEdgeInsets insets = self.tableView.contentInset;
    if(view_is_up&&!up){
        insets.top += move_distance;
        view_is_up = NO;
    }
    else if(!view_is_up&&up){
        insets.top -= move_distance;
        view_is_up = YES;
    }
    self.tableView.contentInset = insets;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

It works beautifully, and is fully configurable via UIView animations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the following code in your animations' block, it should fix it:

```
UIEdgeInsets insets = self.tableView.contentInset;
insets.top -= 50.f;
self.tableView.contentInset = insets;
```

Where self.tableView is an outlet to your UITableView